# How to send money from my Indian bank account/debit card to my PayPal account?

Tags: india, money-transfer, online-payment, paypal

I have a verified PayPal account which I'm using for the last 3-4 yrs.

I want to buy a book from a web site, but PayPal is the only option listed for payment.

I have money in my bank account, but I don't know how I can transfer some amount from my bank to my PayPal account.  I don't have a credit card.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you add the debit card as a funding source?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly transfer money from your Bank Account.

You can use Debit Card to make payments to your paypal account for your current purchase only. Just enter the details of the payment and amount, it would make the necessary deduction from your debit card.

Indian regulations do not allow you to store value in your paypal account. This credits have to be transfered to a Bank account.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer to/from bank account. First, you must establish communication between PayPal and your bank. This has been my experience. Login to your PayPal account and do the following.

**Step 1.** Click My Account tab, then choose 'Profile' 
**Step 2.** Choose My Money, Bank Account. There you can establish your bank account. 
**Step 3.** After you establish your account, you will receive confirmation deposits to your acct within a few days.  
**Step 4.** Once you confirm receiving the deposits, you can send/receive between PayPal and the account.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for the paypal folks.

as I understand it however, when you setup a paypal account, you are granting it access to your back account, so when you make a payment using paypal, it takes money directly from your bank account, and if you get paid for something via paypal, the money goes directly into your account.

If that's not how they paypal account you have is working, then you need to get help from paypal to figure out how to make it work for you.