# Is it possible to receive online payment via paypal in india without creditcard

Tags: india, paypal

I have a paypal Premier account (Verified by PAN and bank account).

I want to receive payments by selling web app on my website.

But I don't verify paypal with credit card. I don't have credit card.

So, I have a doubt. Is it possible to receive payment to my paypal premier account.

Please help me.

Comment: Use a debit card if you don't have a credit card.

Comment: I'm try this one. But it does't accept my debit card.

Comment: Is it need to verify credit card for receiving payments?

Comment: Yes. See here http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9528/how-to-send-money-from-my-indian-bank-account-debit-card-to-my-paypal-account?rq=1

Comment: That question says `Sending money`. My question is `Receiving money`.

Comment: It is the same, have a read through first before jumping to conclusions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. When you list PayPal as the payment option on your website, you would get credits into your PayPal account.

Once the funds are in your PayPal account, they will be automatically credited to your Bank Account within 5 days [RBI Regulation, changing to 3 Days?]. So if you have already linked your Bank Account and PAN it is good to go.